# Updating DSM on Synology 920+ When getting not enough space message

Tags: nas, updates, synology

I need to update DSM on my Synology 920+. In the past I have never had an issue but with the most recent update I receive the below message:

Insufficient system capacity for update

[image]

I have followed all the advice at the linked article, and still receive that message.

I have ssh'd into the machine, and checked the "/" partition to see if there are other things to remove, and there is a directory called ".syno/patch" that takes up a lot of space. I am 90% certain it would be safe to remove the files in that directory all dated July of last year which is approximately the time of my last DSM update.

I would like to confirm that however.

```
tjg@G-n-D_Vault:/.syno/patch$ ls -ltr
total 53176
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    42584 Jul 21  2023 platform.ini
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      566 Jul 21  2023 VERSION
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9158376 Jul 21  2023 bios.ROM
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6402124 Jul 21  2023 rd.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       55 Jul 21  2023 grub_cksum.syno
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     2398 Jul 21  2023 model_r2.dtb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     2398 Jul 21  2023 model.dtb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3453552 Jul 21  2023 zImage
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9158376 Jul 21  2023 bios_r2.ROM
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1080555 Jul 21  2023 H2OFFT-Lx64
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 15947520 Jul 21  2023 updater
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9158376 Jul 21  2023 bios_r1.ROM
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     2398 Jul 21  2023 model_r1.dtb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       98 Jul 21  2023 GRUB_VER
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      523 Jul 21  2023 checksum.syno
```

Comment: What is the link to the article?

Comment: Do you have all the user data backed up elsewhere, and more than one copy of it? If not, now would be a good time to do that. Then, if you have to factory-reset the unit, you have a head start. Also, [Synology:Configuration Backup](https://kb.synology.com/en-global/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/system_configbackup?version=7).

Comment: have you been moving disks around or did you attempt to connect a disk that had been ininitiazed in the NAS by usb? look in each of your /volume# and /volumeUSB# directories to see if you have any files outside the share folder on any volume except the one the DSM OS is stored on (usually /volume1). I had this problem a few months ago, and found that a bunch of DSM files had been stored in a volume root after moving some disks around. don't mess around with files in /, focus on the /volume* directories

Comment: also, if you have no USB volumes plugged in, but you see a /volumeUSB# directory that contains files, those are probably the problem, so move them somewhere else if you want to be cautious, or delete them if you are feeling more "dangerous'